# File as json property how to get it

Tags: c#, json

I load file(image) via html control and send it with other `json` properties to my API. 
The picture property looks:

```
Picture: "data:image/png;abase64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS {a lot of chars}="
```

And in my controller i need to get:
1. File name
2. File extension
3. File to save it in database
4. Width, Height
5. Other info

How I can do that?
I have this:

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(model.Picture);
Image image;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

But image don't have properties with Name, Extension.

Comment: How do you serialize the image? What's the serializer you use for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For height and width you can use the

```
var height = image.Height;
var width = image.Width;
```

As for as the image type is concerned, I found this snippet useful:

```
string mimeType = string.Empty;
Guid id = image.RawFormat.Guid;
if (id == ImageFormat.Png.Guid)
{
    mimeType = "image/png";
}
else if (id == ImageFormat.Bmp.Guid)
{
    mimeType = "image/bmp";
}
else if (id == ImageFormat.Emf.Guid)
{
    mimeType = "image/x-emf";
}
else if (id == ImageFormat.Exif.Guid)
{
    mimeType = "image/jpeg";
}
else if (id == ImageFormat.Gif.Guid)
{
    mimeType = "image/gif";
}
else if (id == ImageFormat.Icon.Guid)
{
    mimeType = "image/ico";
}
else if (id == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid)
{
    mimeType = "image/jpeg";
}
else if (id == ImageFormat.MemoryBmp.Guid)
{
    mimeType = "image/bmp";
}
else if (id == ImageFormat.Tiff.Guid)
{
    mimeType = "image/tiff";
}
else if (id == ImageFormat.Wmf.Guid)
{
    mimeType = "image/wmf";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(model.Picture);
        using (var imageToSave= new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    imageToSave.Write(bytes ,0, bytes.Length);
    imageToSave.Flush();
}
```

Comment: This cannot work as the preamble of the `Picture` property value (`data:image/png;abase64`) is not base 64 encoded.

Comment: sometimes it "abase64" and sometimes it's "base64"... I do not know what file extension it will be. I know only it will be image ;)